# Change post order random through out the entire WordPress

Tags: posts, wp-query, functions, filters

Is it possible to write a filter on global WP Query so that everywhere on WordPress site - all posts will be shown as random order? It will be applicable for any page like home page, blog page, category pages and archive pages. I don't want to add random query on each template instead I can use the filter in functions.php file. 
Your suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.